# Yes/NO window appears even when Password is correct

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.txt");
            username = sr.ReadLine();
            password = sr.ReadLine();
            email    = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
          if  (username == textBox1.Text && password == passwordtextbox.Text)
                MessageBox.Show("You are now successfully logged in.");


           else 
          MessageBox.Show("Username or Password seems invalid, please use email to recover password/username");
          Form2 frm = new Form2();
          // if 
          frm.Show();
          //frm.Show();
          frm.mypass = password;
          frm.myid = username;  




        }
        catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, please correct username/pass or recover");


        }
    }
```

So, my problem was that Form2 Which is the RecoveryPassWord Question Yes/NO, In which the user presses Yes, it prompts them to input their email to send the password, and pressing No, will return it to main screen. However, The problem is that form Yes/No should only appear if the password is wrong, but it appears when the password is right. How should I fix it ?

What I tried was to put these lines

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
          // if 
          frm.Show();
          //frm.Show();
          frm.mypass = password;
          frm.myid = username;
```

in the if statement, that didn't work as it showed me error invalid expression else. I don't know what else could work. If you can help, please do. Thank you.

Comment: Hence the need of indenting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code, properly indented:

```
if (username == textBox1.Text && password == passwordtextbox.Text)
    MessageBox.Show("You are now successfully logged in.");
else 
    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password seems invalid, please use email to recover password/username");

Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.Show();
frm.mypass = password;
frm.myid = username;
```

You need curly braces to group your logic together:

```
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password seems invalid, please use email to recover password/username");

    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
    frm.mypass = password;
    frm.myid = username;
}
```

I'd also suggest replacing `Show()` with `ShowDialog()`, to prevent the user from interacting with the first form while the second is open, and to prevent your code from continuing to run and trying to get the password and username before the user has entered them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the username and password are correctly loaded you can try wrapping the "else" clause in curly brackets like so:

```
else {
    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password seems invalid, please use email to recover password/username");
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just missing your braces around if your if {} else {}.  If you don't use braces, only the immediate line after the else will be part of the if/else.  So you're Form2 code is going to run regardless.

Try using this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.txt");
        username = sr.ReadLine();
        password = sr.ReadLine();
        email    = sr.ReadLine();

        sr.Close();

        if  (username == textBox1.Text && password == passwordtextbox.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are now successfully logged in.");
        }
        else 
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Username or Password seems invalid, please use email to recover password/username");
          Form2 frm = new Form2();
          frm.Show();
          frm.mypass = password;
          frm.myid = username;  
        }
    }
    catch(System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error, please correct username/pass or recover");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the "Else" in curly brackets.

if  (username == textBox1.Text && password == passwordtextbox.Text)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("You are now successfully logged in.");
                }

else 
{
          MessageBox.Show("Username or Password seems invalid, please use email to recover password/username");
          Form2 frm = new Form2();
          // if 
          frm.Show();
          //frm.Show();
          frm.mypass = password;
          frm.myid = username;
}

Comment: @user1769881 - The question is, do you understand _why_ the curly braces did the trick?  :P